# Forecasting the past?

Tags: forecasting, terminology, definition

More of a literacy question that stats, but I'm looking for correct terminology and the Google machine hasn't thrown anything up.

You have explanatory data and observed data for 2000-2010. You have only explanatory variables for 1990-2000. You want to estimate the X for the years 1990-2000, are you forecasting? Estimating? Back predicting? What is the correct terminology?

Comment: I'd call it *backcasting* - which means I agree with @AndyW 's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen it referred to as ***backcasting*** (which is the obverse of *forecasting*). For an example see:

> McShane, Blakely B. & Abraham J. Wyner. 2011. A statistical analysis
>   of multiple temperature proxies: Are reconstructions of surface
>   temperatures over the last 1000 years reliable? *[Annals of Applied
>   Statistics](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1300715170)*
>   5(1):5-44. [PDF Here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4002.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I would call it estimating or perhaps even missing data imputation. It all depends on context.

Is X really causally predicted by your explainatory variables? Or is X only a part of the set that's missing.  I find it hard to think of a real situation. Might help if you provided some more context.

Comment: A company that has only started recording weather dependent data since 2000. But Obviously I have weather records going further back.

Comment: @Will: I see. So what'd be the objective in predicting the unrecorded data for the pre 2000 era?